# Use of the Facebook App Key Hash

Tags: android, facebook

I have developed a sample app, which uses Facebook features, and it is working fine on my device(Samsung Galaxy S). For including Facebook features, i created a dev account(as required) and generated a key hash which i entered in FB dev account.My doubt is(I know it may be very silly to ask this), why do we need to enter this key hash in FB website when we ourselves will be signing the .apk and releasing it in market? Of what use will this key hash be to FB or the device that is downloading my app?

Comment: [update]I was more concerned from android point of view...

Comment: to make your life a living hell of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just another security measure from facebook since it will allow your app to retrieve personal information. Sic, from www.facebook.com/developers :

> A security key used for a more
>   seamless login experience (e.g.,
>   snY1_9SPiOfe_xK2D-RT2ASFl5k).

This is specially important in mobile devices, since you may use it even without logging in: (SIC) From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android_key_hash :

> Single-Sign-On (SSO)
>
> As with the iOS SDK, one of the most
>   compelling features of the Android SDK
>   is Single-Sign-On (SSO). SSO lets
>   users sign into your app using their
>   Facebook identity. If they are already
>   signed into the Facebook Android app
>   on their device they do not have to
>   even type a username and password.
>   Further, because they are signing to
>   your app with their Facebook identity,
>   you will have access to their profile
>   information and social graph.

Comment: Also, to address the signed .apk question - FaceBook don't know or care that your .apk is signed. That's just for Android's benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That was very helpful:).But then,can i register any random String of same length as the hash key? Why do i need to generate it using keytool?

Comment: Short answer: I don't know. You can always try it and see if it works. But my guess is that there must be some check somewhere. You can look for the code here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk . BTW, why don't you want to use your key?

Comment: Just for curiosity...:) And i din get much time to work on your previous comment. Will surely see that... Thanks a lot....:)