# Why do you need app id and key hashes in android?

Tags: android

I have been using Facebook developer and some other sdk's in Android. A lot of places I have seen that they use app id and key hashes. I need to know why do we need this. Why do you need to generate this and what purpose do they do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the Facebook App Key Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501217/use-of-the-facebook-app-key-hash)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501848/4032259) answer, as it seems you are asking the same thing